# Acer one 10 S1002-145A

Tags: system-installation, windows, acer, tablet

I'd like to know if it's possible to install Ubuntu on a new Acer one windows 2 in 1 tablet model S1002-145A. I've searched but the closest thing I found is about the Acer iconia.

Thanks.

Comment: The best advice is in this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2305272 If it doesn't work, you'll have to wait a year for 32 bit uefi support.

Answer (score 1):

I own an Acer One 10 s1002. Managed to run Puppy Linux and Porteus, but do not get a working keyboard or wifi.
Strangely enough I get results if I burn a 32 ISO to USB stick with rufus (MBR) and create an EFI/boot map on the stick with bootia32.efi in it ...
The stick then boots to grub. With the commands set root=(hd0,msdos1) and Linux,initrd + boot I can run Puppy Linux 64, but no keyboard, no wifi.
Ubuntus whether 32 or 64 all boot to grub but following commmands to boot just end
in black screen and having to push the power button, as commented in other posts.

Comment: Its been five months since this answer. Have you found a way to install Debian/Ubuntu on this tablet in this time? (Asking because I'm considering to buy this one as its within my budget).